# Application.EnableEvents = False but textbox_Enter sub still firing in multipage userform VBA

Tags: excel, vba, userform, multipage

I have a multipage userbox called MultiPage1 (as per default).

This comprises 6 pages, all of which have hundreds of textboxes on them, and they all work perfectly...

I have one problem. When `Multipage.Value = 3` it seems to launch a textbox_Enter event, no matter what I do to try to ensure that the textbox *doesn't have* the **focus** throughout the serial.

I of course tried `Application.EnableEvents = False`, but I believe that userforms do not trigger events in the traditional sense of the term.

I cannot for the life of me figure out the problem. But it can be replicated on all of the machines that I have tried.

Interestingly.. when I renamed the troublesome textbox by deleting it, and replacing it with a new textbox with the exact same name.. the problem shifted to the next textbox in the sequence.

`TextBoxTEST1_Enter` no longer fires and now `TextBoxTEST2_Enter` fires instead.

With over 300 textboxes, I am loath to re-create them all!

Any ideas?!

Many thanks,

Phil

Comment: Any event code in your MultiPage control ?

Comment: Sounds like `.TabStop` and `.TabOrder` is what you want to look at. Setting `.TabStop = No` should stop the cursor from automatically going there. The reason the next textbox becomes the problem is because that is the control with the lowest `.TabOrder` so it gets the focus by default.
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/set-the-tab-order-for-controls-2b37e49b-52d1-4f03-ae33-9e6d9c103c99

Comment: @HackSlash this sounds like it could be the answer to my prayers. Looking into this, do I need to set each of those textboxes' settings individually? A la: TextBoxTEST1.Tabstop = False   or can I use MultiPage1.TabStop = False successfully?

Comment: Yes, each one needs `.TabStop = No` and you must manually configure the `.TabOrder` to put the controls in the order which you would like them to be selected automatically. One flowing in to the next.

Comment: Doh, that would have been really helpful to know before I had well over 300 textboxes to edit. Is there definitely no other way @HackSlash?

Comment: There are posts here that have solutions for dynamic userform controls...

Comment: Yeah, you can do it with code by looping through all controls. OR you can select them all and the change will affect all selected objects.

Comment: Posted a work around consisting of only a few code lines (for 6 dummy textboxes) - @PhilipDay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Avoid automatic textbox activation**

A simple work around consists in assigning *zero* `.Width`, *zero* `.Height` and *zero* `.TabIndex` to only one **dummy** textbox per page.

A possible naming convention could be `Dummy1` on 1st page, `Dummy2` on 2nd page etc.

**Code example**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i&
    For i = 1 To Me.MultiPage1.Pages.Count
        Me.Controls("Dummy" & i).Width = 0
        Me.Controls("Dummy" & i).Height = 0
        Me.Controls("Dummy" & i).TabIndex = 0
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Side note**

Trying a similar approach moving the *dummy* textbox *out of sight* (e.g. via a negative `.Left` property) *fails*, as
it shows a blinking cursor at the left page border independant from the chosen value.